# Problems basic auth and authorisation headers

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a webforms application (4.5) that uses forms auth. In the application there is a web api controller that uses basic authentication. (using http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter).

Location tag in web.config is set to allow anon users in the folder the Web Api Controller is in.

Now, using IIS Express from VS2k12, all works fine, I do a call with httpclient to the api, and get some results back, if I send the right credentials ofcourse.

However, when I put my application on IIS7 (on my Win7 pro dev machine) the authentication filter is called, but the Authorization headers are empty!!!!!

I have basic auth installed and enabled on IIS7, just as Form Auth. and Anon Auth, with windows auth disabled?

Anybody got a clue?

EDIT: It seems I am getting the html from the Login.aspx page back after the filter gives a 401 because there are no authorisation headers.

Thanks,
Henk

Answer (score 0):

Are sure about your authorization filter getting hit? My guess is that it does not. Since you have basic authentication enabled in IIS, IIS extracts the credential in Authorization header  and validate it against the Windows domain. If the credential you send in the header is not Windows credential, this validation will fail and there will be a 401 and since you have Forms Authentication enabled, you get directed to loginn.aspx. If you want to implement your own basic authentication, disable the basic authentication in IIS.

Comment: It gets hit, debugger stops there, but auth header is null, IIS, not IIS express